# Solution of a simultaneous equations in $a,b,c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

If $a+b+c=4$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+3(ab+bc+ca)=21$ where $a,b,c \in R$. Then find minimum value of $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$.

Using given information, I calculated that $a^2+b^2+c^2=6$ and $ab+bc+ca=5$. Now by hit and trial, $a=2, b=1$ and $c=1$ satisfy above equations and it is giving correct minimum value of $18$ as well but how do I prove that $(2,1,1)$ is indeed a triplet corresponding to minimum value?

Answer (score 2):

If you expand, you get
$$(a + b)(b + c)(c + a) = a^2b + b^2c + c^2a + ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 + 2abc.$$
This can be "simplified" into
$$(ab + bc + ca)(a + b + c)-abc = 20 - abc$$
using the equations you determined.  Clearly, then, we want to maximize $abc$.  Notice that $a, b,$ and $c$ are the roots of the polynomial equation
$$x^3 - 4x^2 + 5x - abc = 0.$$
This equation must have all real roots, so its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Discriminant) must be non-negative:
\begin{align*}
(-4)^2(5^2) - 4\cdot5^3 - 4 \cdot(-4)^3(abc) - 27(abc)^2 + 18(-4)(5)(abc) &\geq 0\\
\Longrightarrow -27(abc)^2 - 104(abc) - 100 &\geq 0\\
\Longrightarrow (2 - abc)(27abc - 50) &\geq 0.
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$\frac{50}{27} \le abc \le 2,$$
so the maximum value of $abc$ is $2$, yielding a minimum of $18$ for the desired expression.  Furthermore, the minimum value of $abc$ is $\frac{50}{27}$, yielding a maximum of $$20 - \frac{50}{27} = \frac{190}{27}$$ forthe desired expression.